# Product Saving in multiple stores/website in same codebase taking more than 1 min

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am using **Magento 1.9.x** and hosted on **AWS server**. In my store, there are **26 website** and **stores** are available.

**Problem: If I create a product without selecting a website and stores then it is saving product very fast but If I add the product in multiple websites then it is taking more than 1 min to save each product.**

I have checked the core code and print the log and got 128 SQL queries are executing for one store. So if I select more stores while creating the product it is adding 128*number queries. As I understand this is the reason to take time for saving a product. I need as less time as we can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution, The below solution is for enterprise multi store cluster configuration, but it will work with the community too,

Please check the mysql configuration.

https://gist.github.com/iqbalhasnan/6e86523b7942bafd255b#file-data-etc-mysql-my-cnf

Hope this help.